# Android Studio: Submodules in Project Structure Hierarchy

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, build.gradle, git-submodules, android-multi-module

I am building a multi-module app, and I have included the modules in the **project-level settngs.gradle** file, in this manner:

```
include(":sub_module_1")
project(":sub_module_1").projectDir = file("../path/to/sub_module_1_folder")

include(":sub_module_2")
project(":sub_module_2").projectDir = file("../path/to/sub_module_2_folder")

include(":sub_module_3")
project(":sub_module_3").projectDir = file("../path/to/sub_module_3_folder")
```

Then I implement them in the **app-level build.gradle** file, in this manner:

```
implementation project(":sub_module_1")
implementation project(":sub_module_2")
implementation project(":sub_module_3")
```

So far, so good. The project builds and runs as expected.

However, in the **Project Explorer *(both Android & Project tabs),*** some modules appear **inside** the main project, while some appear **outside** of it. But **all of the sub-module file folders are located outside of the main project folder.** Here's an illustration of the Project Explorer (Android):

```
> sub_module_1
  |__ manifests
  |__ java
  |__ res
> main_project
  > app
    |__ manifests
    |__ java
    |__ res
  > sub_module_2
    |__ java
  > sub_module_3
    |__ manifests
    |__ java
    |__ res
> Gradle Scripts
```

**Q: What could be causing this?**